# psycopg2 on Fedora

Tags: python, postgresql, fedora, psycopg2

I'm trying to install psycopg2, using pip, on Fedora.

I get the message:

"pg_config executable not found."

In ubuntu, this problem can be resolved by installing the libpq-dev and python-dev packages.  There's no clear analogous solution in Fedora.

Comment: This is off-topic?  Psycopg2 is a basic requirement for a number of programming projects, including all of the most popular python frameworks that use postgres.  Is this better posted on ServerFault?  I debated it, and then figured it was a developer question.

Comment: This question exists (arguably in duplicate) for ubuntu.  For example, see 6179772.  I guess setting up a development environment in ubuntu is on-topic but fedora not?

Comment: I cannot vote to reopen this question, but I believe it is on topic. Fedora/Red Hat usually install postgresql outside of the path (so you can have multiple versions installed in parallel). To install with pip, do something like export PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin; pip install psycopg2. Of course, you need to make sure that python-devel, libpqxx-devel, and postgresql-devel is installed.

Comment: Most of the time, libs like Psycopg2 will be requirements also of the final product. I guess that's why many people consider this questions as belonging somewhere else (ServerFault or SuperUser, for example).

Comment: Also note that "offtopic" should really say "outside the scope defined by the community" as specified in the close reason. A term that generated [some discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192086/172431)

Comment: This is completely on topic and the number 1 search result in Google for that error message. I really would have appreciated a response here

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are probably searching python-devel and postgresql-devel packages.

Comment: For Python3 in Fedora use `sudo yum install python36-devel` (replace `36` with your version of Python 3).